# How to summarize many-to-one table in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've got two separate sheets we'll call 'Sheet A' and 'Sheet B' with a table on each.

The table on 'Sheet A' has a Many-to-one relationship to the data on the second sheet.

On the second sheet, I'd then like a summary of the data on 'Sheet A' which searches for all rows which match that particular record, then return a Yes/No response by using an 'AND' operator on each matching row.

I know this description does a horrible job at explaining the situation, so I've made the following demonstration spreadsheet ([which you can see in reality](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FQ6MUKZRdCTMjVT2yXtLmnxFAs_5AeV4GL7lAQ7Ljvk/edit?usp=sharing)):

**Sheet A**

[image: Sheet A Example]

**Sheet B**

[image: Sheet B Example]

What I'm trying to automate is the second column of the second sheet (which I've coloured in green).

Any thoughts?

[Also, feel free to let me know if you can think of better wording for this question if you understand what I'm trying to explain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=if(COUNTIFS('Our Animals'!$B:$B,A2,'Our Animals'!$C:$C,"no")=0,"Yes","No")
```

in Animal Types B2, copied down.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it, is by using the following formula.

### Formula

```
=QUERY('Our Animals'!B:C,"SELECT C WHERE B='"& A2 &"' ORDER BY C ASC LIMIT 1")
```

### Screenshot

[image]